# How to load django app models in a project without this project taking responsibility for migrations

Tags: django

Given the following architecture of django projects apps and database schemas:

- There is a django app which I want to share between several django projects.
- Each project has it's own postgresql schema in behind. All schemas live in the same postgresql database.
- One project is owner of the apps data, this project is responsible to run migrations and the data should live in its schema.
- All other projects may access the data from the other projects schema, because they have a proper postgresql search path set.

We already use this concept with an app that has all models set to unmanaged, which works. But database changes always needs to be done manually. I'd like to benefit from django migrations and therefore I want my models either managed or unmanaged.

Do you think app config is good place to change the models meta? Any other suggestions and approaches on how to solve the requirement are also welcome.

Comment: Take a look on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#migration-modules

Comment: Do you want to set the the option `managed` with same value for all models in an app? Do those models have relations to models from other apps?

Comment: All models - it seems like the above mentioned setting is a good option - I'll test this right now.

Comment: Those models might have relations to other models that live in other apps, yes

Comment: In case you have many to many relations between unmanaged models, or unmanaged and managed models, you should pay attention to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in the comments mentioned [setting `MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#migration-modules) works very well. In those projects which should only access the data and which should not be responsible for the migrations you can easily disable the migrations like that:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'yoursharedapp': None
}
```

Note that you need to configure the postgresql role used in the those projects with proper grants and search path.